# Displaying a TableView TabPane

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

HIm using Javafx in my final project for the first time, and i have a problem displaying my TableView in a TabPane.

I have a function named initialize() to create my TableView and fill it and to associate it with the TableView that i created using SceneBuilder ( i specified the same Fx:id for the TableView in my controller of course), the function create as well the Tabs and TabPane and return finally the TabPane.
i called this function inside my Main Controller, but it doesnt display anything.

```
@FXML public TabPane initialize()
{
    //Stage stage = new Stage();
    //BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    TabPane tp = new TabPane();
    Tab ose = new Tab("Liste OS&E");
    ose.setClosable(false);
    TableView  <ose> osetable = new TableView<ose>();
    TableColumn<ose, String> descolumn = new TableColumn<ose, String>("Designation");
    TableColumn<ose, String> articlecolumn = new TableColumn<ose, String>("Article");
    TableColumn<ose, String> fourcolumn = new TableColumn<ose, String>("Fournisseur");
    descolumn.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<ose, String>("designation"));
    articlecolumn.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<ose, String>("article"));
    fourcolumn.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<ose, String>("fournisseur"));
    osetable.setItems(getOSE());
    osetable.getColumns().addAll(descolumn,articlecolumn,fourcolumn);

    ose.setContent(osetable);
    tp.getTabs().add(ose);
    return tp ;
    }
```

and this how i called it to create my page:

```
else if (e.getSource()== gestionprojet)
    {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../V/Gestionprjt.fxml"));
            loader.setController(this);
            stage.setResizable(false);
            stage.setTitle("Gestion de projet - Sofitel Tamuda Bay Beach & Resort");
            Image icon = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("../V/logo-Sofitel.png"));
            stage.getIcons().add(icon);
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane ();
            root.getChildren().add(initialize());
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
    }
```

Can you guys tell me what's wrong with my code? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is: You're using a [`BorderPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html). However a `BorderPane` only displays the `top`, `center`, `bottom`, `right` and `left` `Node`s added using the appropriate properties/setters. Any other children are simply ignored. You are adding the `TabPane` directly to the child list and therefore it's ignored:

```
root.getChildren().add(initialize());
```

Adding it e.g. as `center` would fix this:

```
root.setCenter(initialize());
```

but there is no benefit in wrapping your `TabPane` in a `BorderPane` in this case, since it's the only child of the `BorderPane`. You could also directly set it as the `Scene`'s root:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(initialize());
```

---

Furthermore I'd recommend renaming the `initialize` method, since the `FXMLLoader` would call a `public void public void initialize();` method. This can be a bit confusing, since only your return type prevents it from being called and someone else reading your code (or you in a few weeks) can easily be confused by that fact. Furthermore I'm pretty sure there is no need to annotate the method with `@FXML`.